# How to get the id of the tenant by userid in WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In WSO2 IS I implement a multi-tenant model, creating two tenant. Users enter in IS with your email account. I have tried using the getTenantIdofUser and getUserId operation, but has not been successful.

for example:
    int id  = stub.getTenantIdofUser("gua1@gmail.com");

That method I can use to get the **id of the tenant of a user** to any tenants?

thank you for your help;

Comment: Hi Julio, You can tell us why you need the tenant ID of a user so that we can give you an answer for this. Because tenant ID is something we use internally which the user should not worry about. But again the user domain reflect the tenant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
IdentityUtil.getTenantIdOFUser(username);
```

code snippet to access the tenant ID of the user.

Comment: Hi wattale, the question is: With the user admin/admin (tenant -1234) may consult users belonging to other tenant, how can I do?. when I try to do it from stub or wsdl tells me not exist users.